# Add column of totals pr. field value

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I start with a list of failures that take place in locations

```
failureName, failureLocation
failure a, location 1
failure b, location 1
failure a, location 2
failure a, location 1
<etc>
```

I can transform that into this table by using `summarize count()` by location

```
failureName, failureLocation, count
failure a, location 1, 100
failure a, location 2, 50
failure b, location 1, 10
<etc>
```

I'd like to transform the counts into percent on a per. failure basis, so I need to add a sum per failure name. My goal is to end up with this table:

```
failureName, failureLocation, count, sumPerFailureName
failure a, location 1, 100, 150
failure a, location 2, 50, 150
failure b, location 1, 10, 10
<etc>
```

Suggestions?

Comment: You can put your sample tables into Excel then paste in, looks much nicer, easier to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, to take you from your 2nd table to the 3rd (and extend a calculated column of the percentage):

`let T = 
    datatable(failureName:string, failureLocation:string, ['count']:long)
    [
        'failure a', 'location 1', 100,
        'failure a', 'location 2', 50,
        'failure b', 'location 1', 10,
    ]
;
T
| summarize sumPerFailureName = sum(['count']) by failureName
| join
(
    T
) on failureName
| project failureName, failureLocation, ['count'], sumPerFailureName, percentage = round(100.0 * ['count'] / sumPerFailureName, 2)`