# Find max count for a combination of several fields

Tags: azure-data-explorer

Say I have a table with three fields message, environment and function.

I want to count up the records by message, environment and function, and then select the highest scoring row for any combination.

Getting the counts is easy

```
Table
| summarize count() by message, environment, function
```

...but how do I get just one row with the top count? My solution so far is to create a new table that tallies the counts, then tally max() by environment, function and then do a join, but this seems like an expensive and complicated workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your original question correctly, you may want to look into `summarize arg_max()` as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/arg-max-aggfunction

Answer (score 0):

Ah, just modify the solution here to use max instead of sum

[Add column of totals pr. field value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53163317/add-column-of-totals-pr-field-value)